# Access 2013 ComboBox based on Combobox with Junction Table

Tags: combobox, many-to-many, ms-access-2013

Good day.  I would like to know why a Parameter Request pops up when executing a query.  I have a form with 2 comboboxes where the 2nd one depends on the value in the 1st one.  I do know how to do this when it involves 2 tables.  I am having trouble when there is a many to many relationship.

Table 1: name - Supply_Sources, fields - Source_ID(pk), SupplySourceName

Table 2: name - Warehouse_Locations, fields - WLocation_ID(pk), Location_Name

Table 3 (junction): name - SupplySource_WarehouseLocation, fields - Supply_Source_ID(pk), Location_In_ID(pk)

On my form frmInventoryReceivedInput I have cboSupplySource and cboWLocation.
I populate cboSupplySource with

```
     SELECT [Supply_Sources].[Source_ID], [Supply_Sources].[SupplySourceName] FROM Supply_Sources;
```

I am trying to get a drop down list in the cboWLocation based on the value in cboSupplySource.  I am wanting to see the location names of where the supplies are placed in the warehouse.

I have a requery in cboSupplySource After Update (with cboWLocation as the control name). The SQL that I have come up with so far is:

```
    SELECT Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name,
    SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID, 
    SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID
    FROM Warehouse_Locations RIGHT JOIN (Supply_Sources LEFT JOIN
    SupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON Supply_Sources.Source_ID =
    SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID) ON
    Warehouse_Locations.WLocation_ID = 
    SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID
    WHERE (((Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name)=[frmInventoryReceivedInput].[cboSupplySource]));
```

When it runs, on tabbing out of cboSupplySource, Enter Parameter Value dialogue box pops up, looking for frmInventoryReceivedInput.cboSupplySource input. Nothing I input brings up the correct list in cboWLocation.

Obviously, I do not have the correct select statement. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Tell Access that `frmInventoryReceivedInput` is a member of the `Forms` collection (those forms which are currently open) like this ... `[Forms]![frmInventoryReceivedInput]![cboSupplySources]`  Also remove the semicolon from here: `Location_In_ID;`  If those changes don't fix you up, at least you should get a different error.  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I added [Forms] and removed the ;.  Now, there is no error message (yeah!) but there is still nothing in cboWLocation.

Comment: The value matches the WLocation_ID(pk).  The cboSupplySource shows the text from SupplySourceName field of the Supply_Sources table i.e. "truck 2".  The debug shows the corresponding autonum from the Source_ID field i.e. 1.  So I am looking to display in cboWLocations the records (i.e. SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID) in the junction table where SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID = 1.  But I want the corresponding text from the Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name field e.g. 'storeroom'.

Comment: That's correct.  I'm thinking I haven't linked the fields properly between the  pk (numeric IDs) and the other fields.

Comment: hmmm.  Well I now have a drop down list.  However ... cboSupplySource has a drop down list of 11 items. There should be a maximum of 3 locations in cboWLocation corresponding to each of the items in cboSupplySource i.e item 1 in SupplySource corresponds to 3 items in WLocation. Item 2 also 3, Item 4 of the Sources can go into 2 locations in WLocation.  The change you offered did indeed give me a list of items but they are way off from what I was expecting.  Item 1 in cboSupply had 6 items in cboWLocation.  Some items had 0 corresponding.  None matched correctly.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide me with a generic template for my scenario - two tables and a junction table (many-to-many) with 2 fields in each table, and 2 combo boxes with the second dependent on the first?  I can't seem to find that anywhere.

Comment: thanks and here is the link http://www.4shared.com/file/epWHJx1Hce/TCTR_2015_-_copy.html.  As you will see I'm just getting started, so any other suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: When I try to save the change, the message is 'Characters found after end of SQL statement'.  Sorry, I don't know what is wrong with your statement.

Answer (score 0):

For cboWLocation try the recordSource query:

```
SELECT Warehouse_Locations.Location_Name
FROM Warehouse_Locations INNER JOIN (Supply_Sources INNER JOIN
SupplySource_WarehouseLocation ON Supply_Sources.Source_ID =
SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Supply_Source_ID) ON
Warehouse_Locations.WLocation_ID = 
SupplySource_WarehouseLocation.Location_In_ID
WHERE ((Supply_Sources.SupplySourceName)=([Forms]![frmInventoryReceivedInput].[cboSupplySource]))
```

Be aware, that the combobox columns have to be set to columncount 1 in this case with appropriate column width, because you said you only want to see the location names. Further, you should be sure that cboWLocation is not bound to a Control Source, to not overwrite anything.

You can apply it in VBA at the cboWLocation Enter Event.
In the following code example, the combobox cboWLocation is only updated, if there is a value in combobox cboSupplySource.

```
Private Sub cboWLocation_Enter()
    If not (isNull(Me!cboSupplySource) Or Me!cboSupplySource.ListIndex = -1) then
        Me.cboWLocation.RowSource = strSQL 'Put here the previous mentioned SQLString
    End if    
End Sub
```

HINT: It would be better for performance, when you change the bound column in cboSupplySource to the PK SourceID instead of the name. (With two columns in combobox cboSupplySource) Then use this PK to compare in your WHERE statement instead of the name. this is what keys in tables are for.

Edit: In the WHERE statement, maybe you have to put the namecomparison between ' ' because it is a string

Comment: Thanks.  I will test this shortly.

Comment: when I exit cboSupplySource a pop up occurs looking for parameter value for supply_sources.supply_source_id.  Incidentally, I was provided with an answer from HansUp, (but I can't seem to mark it  that way).  His answer was SELECT sw.Supply_Source_ID, w.Location_Name
FROM Warehouse_Locations AS w INNER JOIN (Supply_Sources AS s INNER JOIN SupplySource_WarehouseLocation AS sw ON s.Source_ID = sw.Supply_Source_ID) ON w.WLocation_ID = sw.Location_In_ID
WHERE (((sw.Supply_Source_ID)=[forms]![frmInventoryReceivedInput]![cboSupplySource]));    s, w and sw refer to the 3 tables